# Is it correct way to copy R vector to another vector?

Tags: r, vector, copy

I want to know how copy vector to another vector.

```
ci95=function(x)
{
    t.value = qt(0.975, length(x) - 1)
    standard.error = se(x)
    ci = t.value * standard.error
    rt = c(mean(x) - ci , mean(x) + ci)
    return(rt)
}
```

`ci95` function will return vector `"[1] a , b"`

```
base = function(x)
{
    rt = c(mean(x), var(x), se(x), ci95(x))
    return(rt)
}
```

and `base` function will return `"[1] mean, var, se, a, b"`

is it correct way or not?

I think it has possible to wrong like this

`[mean, var, se, [a, b]]`....maybe or not

`if "Avector = c(Bvector, Cvector)"` is a wrong way,

teach me the correct way to copy `A vector` to `B vector`

Comment: I have no idea what you asking here, but `ci95` and `base` look ok to me

Comment: OK for what? You can't have a vector nested inside a vector. Lists can do that, though.

Comment: Thanks. I want this answer.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, I was only referring to `ci95` and `base` (as clearly stated), surely not to `[mean, var, se, [a, b]]` because I didn't understand his question/english (as also clearly stated)

Answer (score 1):

In R, the only structure that can accommodate `[mean, var, se, [a, b]]` type of structures are lists. It would make sens to organize them in a predictable manner so that you're able to extract elements from it with ease. If you want to go for the list, your statement in `base` should be

```
rt = list(mean(x), var(x), se(x), ci95(x)).
```

I would suggest you name the elements, too, e.g.

```
rt = list(mean = mean(x), var = var(x), se = se(x), ci95 = ci95(x))
```